# Marketing Cloud Smart Capture Form Validation

Tags: marketing-cloud

We would like to put validation on field values of Smart Capture form. 
For e.g. if mobile number is field is present in Smart capture form then we want to put validation like number should start with country code and it contains certain length etc.

Is it possible to achieve it using  standard smart capture form? or we have to develop complete form using HTML/JS for this validation?

Thanks and Regards,
Sushant Edlabadkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve that with the Smart Capture functionality so you have to implement it using HTML/JS.

Comment: I agree with Fromero but developing this should not be a huge requirement either.
Let me know if you need some examples.

Comment: Thanks. Based on information provided in below link am able to do validation on submit button however we cannot block record insertion so custom code is the only option for this requirement.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_validate_fields_in_a_smart_capture_form_with_javascript.htm&type=5