# SmartCapture Submission Validation in Journey Builder

Tags: journeybuilder, form, smart-capture

Is it possible to validate a Smart Capture submission in Journey Builder?
Thank you.

Comment: Does  [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260017/marketing-cloud-smart-capture-form-validation) answer?